# how to consolidate the different columns into single column from different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBQno.jpg]

I am trying to consolidate the individual faculty timetable into one master timetable.

Comment: So are you familiar with SQL and if not do a google search on how to Concat Column names also look up how to use `JOINS` here is a good link to use [Find what you need easily](http://www.google.com)

Comment: What determines that cat goes with fan? Is there an ID common to both tables because you cannot rely on an unsorted order

Comment: It looks like you would need to use Union to combine the tables together.  Check the link below for some example on how to use Union.  I would also suggest you to use JOIN, but I'm not sure if you have any common column in both rows or if you have a third table with common rows with the other two tables. http://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-union.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda or alternatively, LINQ to accomplish this.  I have provided a working example.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Container> table1 = new List<Container>()
            {
                new Container { Column1 = "Sam", Column2 = "Fred" },
                new Container { Column1 = "Arnold", Column2 = "Frank" }
            };

            List<Container> table2 = new List<Container>()
            {
                new Container { Column1 = "Whitwicky", Column2 = "Flintstone" },
                new Container { Column1 = "Schwartz", Column2 = "Sinatra" }
            };

            var result = Example.MergeTables(table1, table2);

            foreach (var r in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.Column1 + "\t\t" + r.Column2);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Container> MergeTables(List<Container> table1, List<Container> table2)
        {
            return table1.Select((value, index) =>
                new Container
                {
                    Column1 = value.Column1 + " " + table2[index].Column1,
                    Column2 = value.Column2 + " " + table2[index].Column2
                });

        }
    }

    public class Container
    {
        public string Column1 { get; set; }
        public string Column2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ or lambda is simply a query language. You can use it against almost any data collection.

Comment: i am quite new for asp so can u clarify with table example

Comment: I would recommend looking into ADO.NET EntityFramework, here is a link to get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb399572(v=vs.100).aspx